# RegEx finding labels

Tags: regex

I want to return valid "labels". A label is defined by a string ending with ":".
Labels cannot start with a number but can contain numbers.
A ":" in a comment (starting with ";") shall be excluded.

**Valid**

```
Label:
label:
LABEL:
Label1:
random:
```

**Invalid**

```
;text:
; text:
1Label:
```

Comment: Did you try anything on your own?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try following regex.

```
^[^\d;][^:]+(?=:)
```

**Details**:

- `^[^\d;]`: first character is not number and `;`
- `[^:]+(?=:)`: matches any characters until `:`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/vRFA1Y/1)